# tomcat+josso1.8.6+spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, single-sign-on, josso

I use JOSSO 1.8.6. I configure all in the Tomcat lib directory file related to JOSSO, and I'm also doing all configuration in web application[spring] WEB-INF file. I got the below URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestLogin/?josso_cmd=login_optional
 &josso_back_to=http://localhost:8080/TestLoginDemo/josso_security_check
 &josso_partnerapp_id=TestLoginDemo
```

But my question is:

My parent web application is --TestLogin means this application login page is main to display all the other web application [child web application].

I have 3 child application

1. TestLoginDemo
2. jossoLogin1
3. JossoLoginDemo

All are spring application.

I hit in browser mean URL is `http://localhost:8080/TestLoginDemo`

So the below URL I see

```
http://localhost:8080/TestLogin/?josso_cmd=login_optional
 &josso_back_to=http://localhost:8080/TestLoginDemo/josso_security_check
 &josso_partnerapp_id=TestLoginDemo
```

But after the successful login I find the `TestLogin` flow means not transfer to the `TestLoginDemo`.

So what is the way if I have to carry on flow for `TestLoginDemo`?

And; after success this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestLogin/?josso_cmd=login_optional
 &josso_back_to=http://localhost:8080/TestLoginDemo/josso_security_check
 &josso_partnerapp_id=TestLoginDemo
```

login page I got below URL in success:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestLogin/login.htm
```

instead of the below correct URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestLoginDemo/login.htm
```

Could anybody guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why `josso_cmd=login_optional`, did you set it up like this ? By default this is unecessary to specify the `josso_cmd` argument.

  - In order to get back to the original application, you have to use `josso_partnerapp_ctx` argument (don't forget to encode URL), this will be passed to the security check page that will lead you to this page if the security check is sucessfull

Usually, URL looks like this:

https://login.domain.com/josso/signon/login.do?josso_back_to=https://site.domain.com/Josso/Check&josso_partnerapp_host=site.domain.com&josso_partnerapp_ctx=https%3a%2f%2site.domain.com%2fhome.html